# How to understand $G_{k_0}\bigcap R_n\subset D_n$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

$G\subset R^N$ is a measurable set, $mG< +\infty$ ,and $\varphi_n(x)\rightarrow \varphi(x)$ in measure. $\sigma\in R,k_0\in Z^+$,$f(x,u)$ meets the Caratheodory condition
(for almost all of  $x\in G$,$f(x,u)$ is continue about $u$,and for every $u\in R$ ,$f(x,u)$ is a measurable function about $x$ on $G$).

$$
G_{k_0}=\{x\in G:\forall u\in R,\text{ if } |u-\varphi(x)|<\frac{1}{k_0},
\text{ then } |f(x,u)-f(x,\varphi(x))|<\sigma
\}
$$

$$
R_n=\{x\in G:|\varphi_n(x)-\varphi(x)|<\frac{1}{k_0}\}
$$

$$
D_n=\{x\in G:|f(x,\varphi_n(x))-f(x,\varphi(x))|<\sigma
\}
$$
show that :  $G_{k_0}\cap R_n\subset D_n$

Comment: @uniquesolution I try to make the $u=\varphi (x)$， but nothing I can get,.Do you know how to show it ?

Comment: Something must be wrong here, because it is trivial that $G_{k_0}\cap R_n\subset D_n$, by the definition of the three sets, and you don't have to use all the information given about convergence in measure etc. Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?

Comment: @uniquesolution In fact ,I don't know which condition is necessary. So , some conditions is not necessary. And I leaven out $mG<+ \infty$.I have added it .